# BGP: Longest prefix vs. shortest path

Tags: routes, shortest-path, bgp, longest-prefix

Assume that an autonomous system AS0 receives the following two announcements from its peers:

AS1: 42.0.0.0/8  with path length 10

AS2: 42.0.0.0/16 with path length 20

Now, where a packet with destination address 42.0.0.1 will be routed by AS0?

To AS1 because it has the shorter path or to AS2 because it has the longer prefix?

Answer (score 2):

As far as BGP is concerned:

- They are two different destination prefixes.
- BGP only has one candidate route (path) for destination prefix 42.0.0.0/**8**, hence only one route to pick from, which automatically wins the best path selection, and will be installed in the forwarding table (FIB).
- Similarly, BGP only has one candidate route (path) for destination prefix 42.0.0.0/**16**, hence only one route to pick from, which automatically wins the best path selection, and will be installed in the forwarding table (FIB).
- Hence, we end up with two routes in the forwarding table (FIB): 42.0.0.0/**8**, and also 42.0.0.0/**16**.
- When a packet arrives and a forwarding decision needs to be made in the forwarding plane, the forwarding hardware will always pick the most specific route. Note that BGP is already out of the picture at this point.
- For example, a packet with destination address 42.0.0.1 will use route 42.0.0.0/**16**, and a packet with destination address 42.1.0.1 with use route 42.0.0.0/**8**.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/bgp-decision-process-priority-vs-longest-match). In your case the packet is routed to AS2 because longest prefix match will always be looked at first.